# java regex expression to get everything in closed brackets

Tags: java, regex

I would like to know if it is possible to have a java regex expression for getting everything inbetween brackets

as in `[any string]` and return `any string`

I was thinking something like `[? . ]?` I guess cause `[?` searches for one open bracket and the `.` means any character.

Comment: Only as long as there is no nesting.

Comment: Go try yourself: http://scriptular.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex:

```
(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex :

`(?<=\[).*(?=\])`

Answer (score 0):

No need for look-arounds. Try this:

```
\[([^\]]+)
```

This matches an opening bracket and then captures everything which is not a closing bracket, up to the next closing bracket. You can get the captured back-reference with `$1`